# Excel user-defined function not called on cell update

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a user-defined function written in VBA that updates colors in a drawn shape (traffic light consisting of three circles). The call in a worksheet cell looks somehow like this:

```
setTrafficLight(A1, "Oval 1", "Oval 2", "Oval 3")
```

where A1 is a cell containing e.g. "green" or "red". The other parameters are the names of the shapes.

I had a problem that the function was called and deleted the undo history (calling a user-defined function in Excel does disable older undo entries). To fix this, I registered an empty undo function via

```
Application.OnUndo "Undo SetTrafficLight", "undoSetTrafficLight"
```

In my setTrafficLight function, `Application.Volatile` is set to `False` so that the function does not get called every time any value on the sheets changes. But now the function isn't even called when the input value in A1 changes. With `Application.Volatile = True` it works, but then undo is not working properly. If I completely remove `Application.Volatile` then the updating works correctly, but only one level of undo can be used.

Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: This question may belong to http://www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `Worksheet_Change` event?

something like this:

*this should work for A1 cell, but could be easily adjusted for others*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
      Call setTrafficLight
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is an idea I haven't considered yet, but unfortunately it wouldn't integrate very well given the fact that we change the input cell locations regularly.

Comment: If you would skip the IF you should be able to call setTrafficLight function on every change in this worksheet, is that the problem?

Comment: No, that's no problem. Will do that. Thanks.